# Powermock doesn't run on Java1.5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermock

Doesn't Powermock run on Java 1.5? I am getting following exception

```
cannot access org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
...lib\powermock-mockito-1.6.2-full.jar (org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.class)
    [javac] class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
    [javac] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
    [javac] import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac] 1 error
    [javac] Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated!!

I have downgraded power mock version to 1.5 and i am getting different exception now.

[image: Stack trace and list of jars]

I found that javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar has been built on Java1.6 and replaced it with older version of javassist-3.16.1-GA. I am getting below weird exception now. I believe i do not have proper versions of jars and it dependency. Any suggestion/thoughts?

[image: Stack trace:]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what kind of project are you working on in 2016 that is running on Java5? And what makes you turn to PowerMock?

Comment: Looks like that you are trying to start PowerMock with [javaagent](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/PowerMockAgent) (according to class path information), but you don't use JVM parameter `-javaagent` parameter when start test. I have a question: are you sure that you need use PowerMock with jUnit Rule and javaagent? May be [this approach](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule) will also work for you?

Answer (score 3):

PowerMock version 1.6.0 and later is built with Java 6, and hence does not support  Java 5.  From their [change log for version 1.6.0](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/blob/master/changelog.txt#L72):

> PowerMock now builds for Java 6 and not Java 5.

If you can't upgrade Java you must downgrade PowerMock to 1.5.6 or earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Luke! I appreciate it !! I have downgraded power mock to 1.5.5 but now i am getting bad version number exception                                          java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
 at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockClassTransformer.<clinit>(PowerMockClassTransformer.java:41)
 at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockAgent.<clinit>(PowerMockAgent.java:42)

Comment: @Javee: that looks to me like one of the JAR files somewhere in your project is built for Java 6 or later.  I can't tell what JAR that would be from that stacktrace, and I certainly can't go through the list of those used by your tests because you haven't provided that information.  I would suggest editing your question to include (a) the stacktrace in your comment, and (b) a list of all the JAR files used by your tests.